# Где хранится блок инициализации?

Tags: java

В какой области памяти JVM хранится статический и не статический блоки инициализации ?
Конструктор так же как и блок инициализации, выполняется при создании обьекта класса, хранится в стеке, значит и блок инициализации так же хранится в стеке ?
Обьясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Конструктор - это функция, он хранится там, где хранятся функции (вангую - это не стек). Конструктору всё равно, где хранится объект класса.

Comment: Очень интересно но ничего не понятно.

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что `конструктор так же как и блок инициализации хранится в стеке`?

Comment: Данные хранятся в heap и stack memory, описание классов и сам код - в method area. Единственный способ  воздействовать на последнюю область памяти - ClassLoader.  Почитайте про JVM runtime memory.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на материал пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы перепутали: в стеке хранятся локальные переменные из конструкторов, но не сами конструкторы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проведем простой эксперимент, в котором будет видно, что конструктор это специальный метод с именем `<init>`, а статическая инициализация класса - `<cinit>`, т.о. их локальные переменные во время их выполнения хранятся в стеке:

```
jshell> class Test {
   ...>     Test() {
   ...>         new Exception().printStackTrace();
   ...>     }
   ...> }
|  created class Test

jshell> class Demo {
   ...>     static {
   ...>         System.out.println("Demo class init");
   ...>         new Test();
   ...>     }
   ...> }
|  created class Demo

jshell> new Demo()
Demo class init
java.lang.Exception
    at REPL.$JShell$11$Test.<init>($JShell$11.java:7)
    at REPL.$JShell$12$Demo.<clinit>($JShell$12.java:8)
    at REPL.$JShell$13.do_it$($JShell$13.java:7)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.DirectExecutionControl.invoke(DirectExecutionControl.java:227)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.RemoteExecutionControl.invoke(RemoteExecutionControl.java:116)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.DirectExecutionControl.invoke(DirectExecutionControl.java:125)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.ExecutionControlForwarder.processCommand(ExecutionControlForwarder.java:144)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.ExecutionControlForwarder.commandLoop(ExecutionControlForwarder.java:262)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.Util.forwardExecutionControl(Util.java:77)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.Util.forwardExecutionControlAndIO(Util.java:138)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.RemoteExecutionControl.main(RemoteExecutionControl.java:70)
$3 ==> Demo@4edde6e5
```

--- update ---
в дискуссии в комментариях выяснилось, что вопрос был шире.

читаем матчасть: [JVM Specification: Chapter 2. The Structure of the Java Virtual Machine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5)
раздел 2.5

- код размещается в Method Area (п.2.5.4)
- константы в Run-Time Constant Pool (п.2.5.5)
- объекты хранятся в куче (п.2.5.3)
- данные (локальные примитивные переменные и ссылки на объекты в куче) и промежуточные результаты, а также ссылки на константы и таблица динамических (виртуальных) методов в специальной структуре Frame (раздел 2.6).

Frame создается при каждом вызове и хранится в стеке (также может размещаться в куче, а в стеке лежать только ссылка), собственно их мы и видим как строки в стек-трейсе.

Comment: ОП не спрашивает где `хранятся локальные переменные`, а где хранятся сами блоки инициализации.

Comment: @RomanC возможно я не правильно понял вопрос. расшифруйте что вы понимаете под "хранятся".

Comment: Имеется в виду, в какой области памяти jvm находится блок инициализации. Извините за не точный вопрос.

Comment: @Ramiz Я тут не задавал вопрос. Я просто дал вам понять, что вы не правильно поняли вопрос. ОП вам уже расшифровал, что имеется ввиду код, а не данные.